# How to Sum fields that are in array?

Tags: mysql, sum

I have an array with for example the following values: $id_list=array(1,2,9,37);

Now I have a query and it should return the sum of all the values in a table where the Id's match with the array. This is my query now:

```
$tr_query="SELECT SUM(Value1), SUM(Value2) 
FROM table WHERE Id IN(".implode(",",$id_list).")";
```

So if the SUM of all the field with id 1,2,9 and 37 is 109350, it should return that value.

Thanks!

Comment: And doesn't it? Did you try it? Should work fine.

Comment: Just make sure your array contents are all integers not requiring additional escaping when you `implode()` them into a string

Comment: For every ID it returns something, so the IN doesn't work I think?

Comment: Impossible, unless you also have a `GROUP BY` clause. Without the `GROUP BY` it will return only one row. That's how aggregate functions like `SUM()` work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$tr_query="SELECT SUM(SELECT value1 FROM table WHERE id IN (".implode(",",$id_list).")), SUM(SELECT value2 FROM table WHERE id IN (".implode(",",$id_list).")) FROM dual";
```